# Using 3DES decryption to get a specific result

Tags: 3des

I want to get 3DES to get a predictable result; assume I have:

```
key: [any]

data: [any]
```

then I want to apply 3DES decryption on key and data to get a specific result, such as:

```
decrypted 3DES: 12121212121212121212121212121212
```

Is this possible in theory?

Comment: Pick any key and let the data be the encryption of the target string (also note that 3DES by itself only encrypts 64-bit blocks).

Comment: Changed the question, it seems you wanted a *specific* result, not a *predictable* result. You could of course say that you can predict specific details for a specific results, e.g. consisting of just ones and zeros. However, the only viable technique for that is to first pick a result and then encrypt that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to apply 3DES decryption on key and data to get a specific result. Is this possible in theory?

Sure. 3DES is a functionally correct encryption scheme for any fixed key, so for any message there exists a(t least one) corresponding ciphertext value.

So if you want to have a specific decryption result $m$ using a specific key $k$, you simply choose the ciphertext $c$ as $c=E_k(m)$ and by correctness $D_k(c)=D_k(E_k(m))=m$.